# How can i refactor these functions?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

So basically, in game, I have a "wall validator", which checks if wall meets all of the requirements. Then, based on which requirement have failed, program calls appropriate message function.

> Here is the code, where I call wall validator:

```
    internal void PlaceWall(Vector2 wallStartPosition, Vector2 wallEndPosition)
    {
        _wallStartPosition = wallStartPosition;
        _wallEndPosition = wallEndPosition;

        _wallValidator.InitializeVectors(wallStartPosition, wallEndPosition);
        if (_wallValidator.WallDoesNotMeetTheRequirements())
        {
            _wallValidator.SendAppropriateMessage();
            return;
        }

        PlaceNewWall();
    }
```

> Right now I check all requirements two times in two different functions here they are in wall validator:

```
    internal bool WallDoesNotMeetTheRequirements()
    {
        if (WallPositionIsBeyondBoard()||
            PlayerUsedAllAvailableWalls()||
            WallIsNotOnTheSameLine() ||
            WallIsTooLong() ||
            WallTilesHavePairCoordinates() ||
            WallDoesNotCoverTwoSolidTiles() ||
            WallInterceptsWithOtherWall())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    internal void SendAppropriateMessage()
    {
        if (WallPositionIsBeyondBoard())
            _player.output?.DisplayWallHasPositionBeyondBoardMessage();
        if (PlayerUsedAllAvailableWalls())
            _player.output?.DisplayNotEnoughWallsMessage();
        if (WallIsNotOnTheSameLine())
            _player.output?.DisplayWallIsNotOnTheSameLineMessage();
        if (WallIsTooLong())
            _player.output?.DisplayWallIsTooLongMessage();
        if (WallTilesHavePairCoordinates())
            _player.output?.DisplayWallTilesHavePairCoordinatesMessage();
        if (WallDoesNotCoverTwoSolidTiles())
            _player.output?.DisplayWallDoesNotCoverTwoSolidTilesMessage();
        if (WallInterceptsWithOtherWall())
            _player.output?.DisplayWallInterceptsWithOtherWallMessage();
    }
```

**How would you refactor these functions?**
I've tried making a "Requirement" class, which accepts "check function" and "message to send" in it's constructor, but have failed. This option does not work in testing environment. The reason is that I am using NUnit testing framework, and when I tried to test wall placement without assigning "ConsoleOutput" (Class, which implements all of the message functions), I would always get a "NullPointer" exception at the point of "Requirement" class initialization.
So, basically, what Im trying to say in code is "Send *appropriate* message to the output *if it is not null*, but if it is, then *just return true*". But with every new requirement in current state, i would need to add check function in two different places.
I don't really like this option of "double checking requirement and sending message" and I feel like I'm missing a simple answer to this problem.
P.S. Sorry for my broken english ;D, hope I explained everything that I could in a way that you can understand.

Comment: Make an enum for all of the failure cases and success. Have `WallDoesNotMeetTheRequirements` return the enum value. Pass the enum value to your message function. You could also put the messages in a dictionary keyed by the enum value and easily look them up.

Comment: `WallDoesNotMeetTheRequirements()` is not needed - return the bool from `SendAppropriateMessage()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, make a enum that returns the result of the operation, inclusive different error cases.

```
public enum WallPlacementResult{
    Success,
    NotOnTheSameLine,
    TooLong
    ...
}

WallPlacementResult CheckWallRequirements(){
      if (WallIsNotOnTheSameLine()) return WallPlacementResult.NotOnTheSameLine;
      if (WallIsTooLong()) return WallPlacementResult.TooLong;
      ...
    return WallPlacementResult.Success;
}

void SendAppropriateMessage(WallPlacementResult result)
{
    switch(result){
        case WallPlacementResult.NotOnTheSameLine:
             _player.output?.DisplayWallHasPositionBeyondBoardMessage();
        break;
        case WallPlacementResult.TooLong:
        ...
    }
}
```

Another option might be to use something like a [generic result object](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults). Overall I would recommend delegating any UI task, like showing messages, to the UI layer. The checking logic may benefit of being placed in a lower layer to make it easier to unit test etc.

Comment: Perfect. That will do. Thanks ^_^